# Dynamic Jquery selector not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an object that has a tag id among other things. What Im trying to do is to add a `onchange` listener to that element but its not working. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srzCT/) that represents what Im trying to do.

html

```
<select id="select_one">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    obj = {
        select: "select_one",
        other: "otherParam"
    };
    var id = obj.select;
    $("#"+id).on('change', function(){
        alert('changed');
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: It's working, if you add jquery

Comment: dont tell me you havent added jquery in your code also!!!SO is not a place for debugging!!

Comment: it is in my code thats why I was wondering as I have done this many times \__(oO)__/ so Im going to have to look at the timing of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **haven't added the `jQuery` library in your fiddle** (available at the left top corner)

You code is working fine.  Check this [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/srzCT/1/)

Also when you use it local environment don't forget to add the jQuery library like

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with  your `code`.

You forgot to add the jquery in your fiddle.

Here is your [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/srzCT/5/).

Comment: did you just cracked a joke..or are you trying to be sarcastic??

Comment: @MESSIAH Lol ...Even I upvoted the  fastest answer ..So just move on ....deleting (or) leaving it alone, doesn't make any sense  with this answer :)